# rcp application without workspace creation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, startup, rcp, workspace

I would like to have an rcp application, that does not create any `workspace` folder at startup.
My `rcp` application does not require to save any plugin or user data persistently.  For end user, the workspace creation seems to be an confusing and annoying side effect. How can I avoid this?

It seems to me that each `rcp` application requires the plugin `org.eclipse.core.resources`, whereas the class `ResourcesPlugin` creates the workspace at startup.

I am aware of the `-data <workspace_dir>` option in order to specify a different workspace location, but I would like to avoid workspace creation at all.

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 10):

From http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

```
eclipse -data @none
```

> **@none**
>
> Indicates that the corresponding location should never be set
>   either explicitly or to its default value. For example, an RCP style
>   application which has no user data may use osgi.instance.area=@none to
>   prevent extraneous files being written to disk. @none must not be
>   followed by any additional path segments.